# quicksight.getSessionEmbedUrl is not a function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-quicksight

I successfully generated a dashboard embed url following https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sample/blob/master/OpenIdAuthentication/lambda/index.js (although I did just find https://embed-workshop.learnquicksight.online/1.introduction.html and wish I had found it before) but when I tried to generate a session embed url to enable "authoring ports allow the user to create QuickSight assets, just like they can in the AWS console for QuickSight" I get this error in my CloudWatch logs:

> quicksight.getSessionEmbedUrl is not a function

I double checked the AWS docs here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/QuickSight.html#getSessionEmbedUrl-property

and even copy/pasted the code example in my lambda function and am still getting the error.

Am I just forgetting something or is this an error in the documentation?

Relevant code snippet:

```
var quicksight = new AWS.QuickSight()

...

quicksight.getSessionEmbedUrl(sessionParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log('Get Session Embed Url:::::::::::::::: ', err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        console.log( 'Get Session Embed Url:::::::::::::::: ', data)
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.body = JSON.stringify(data)
        callback(null, res)
    }
```

Also when I console log out quicksight just to make sure it is initiated correctly I get this in my CloudWatch logs:

```
INFO    quicksight Service {
  config: Config {
    credentials: CognitoIdentityCredentials {
      expired: false,
      ...
```

So it looks like what I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those finding this question because their lambda does not seem to be aware of some functions documented in the AWS-SDK.

The problem is indeed that the version bundled with the Lambda runtime is not the latest. 
You can find which version is bundled [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-nodejs.html)

The solution is to create a lambda layer that includes the latest version and use it in your lambda.
It's quite simple to do. I found [this guide](https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e) quite helpful.

**TLDR**:
Creating your layer with the latest aws-sdk:

```
mkdir my-lambda-layer
cd my-lambda-layer
mkdir nodejs
cd nodejs
npm init
npm install --save aws-sdk
cd ..
zip -r layer.zip nodejs
```

Use *layer.zip* file when creating your layer

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you found the answer to this one, but for me the problem was the version of the SDK bundled with the Lambda runtime (. Updated that and no more 'not a function' error.

Comment: How did you update it?

Comment: @IgorJanković see my answer for detailed steps

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/QuickSight.html) clearly say that the function generateEmbedUrlForAnonymousUser exists. To get it to work, include quicksights api json file in your project and provide its location in the quicksights config object.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const https = require('https');
var quicksight = new AWS.Service({
    apiConfig: require('./quicksight-2018-04-01.min.json'),
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});
```